# Easiest way to add a controller-defined CSS class in an ember handlebars template

Tags: ember.js

I have the following template:

```
...
<i class="icon-fixed-width {{myIcon}} icon-4x"></i>
...
```

And my controller has `myIcon` defined as a simple string:

```
App.NodesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    ...
    myIcon          : 'icon-cloud',
    ...
});
```

(this setting is in controller. The background is that I want to reuse the template for different controllers, so that just by 'configuring' each controller I get a different icon)

The problem is that `{{myIcon}}` produces a surprising result (to me, at least!):

```
<i class="icon-fixed-width <script id='metamorph-8-start' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>icon-cloud<script id='metamorph-8-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></script> icon-4x"></i>
```

How can I achieve the expected result:

```
<i class="icon-fixed-width icon-cloud icon-4x"></i>
```

by accessing `myIcon` in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{{bindAttr class='myIcon'}}` ...[Reference to bindAttribute Classes](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/)

Comment: Thanks. This completely overwrites the class, so I lose `icon-fixed-width` and `icon-4x`. I guess I can workaround that problem, though.

Comment: Use as {{bindAttr class=':icon-fixed-width :icon-4x myIcon'}}

Comment: If instead of defining myIcon in the controller as a string, I define it as a funcion that returns a string, it is not working anymore. Do you know a workaround for that? That would help me in making my code more generic ...

Comment: it should not be a function, you should have it as a computed property

Comment: myIcon: function(){ return "myclass";}.property()   will do your work

Comment: Thanks. I am slowly starting to understand the whole thing, hopefully :)